# Determine the long, longer and longest ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, arraylist

I have three (3) ArrayLists of different sizes and I want to know which is the long, longer and longest.
I came up with this solution which works fine, but it doesn't look optimised enough. I will like someone to optimise it for me.
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class LongLongerLongest {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        /**
         * Generated ArrayLists for testing
         */
        List<String> first = Arrays.asList("qw", "sd", "asw");
        List<String> second = Arrays.asList("qw", "sd", "r4", "asw", 
"qw", "sd", "r4", "asw", "r4", "asw");
        List<String> third = Arrays.asList("qw", "sd", "r4", "asw", 
"r4", "asw", "oiu");


        String result = sortLists(first,second, third);
        System.out.println(result);
    }



    static String sortLists(List<String> firstList, List<String> 
secondList, List<String> thirdList) {

        /**
         * declare a list to hold all sizes
         */
        List<Integer> listOfSizes = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> longList;
        List<String> longerList;
        List<String> longestList;

        /**
         * Add the size of all array to the listOfSizes list and sort
         */
        listOfSizes.add(firstList.size());
        listOfSizes.add(secondList.size());
        listOfSizes.add(thirdList.size());
        Collections.sort(listOfSizes);

        /**
         * Searching for the longest
         */
        if (firstList.size() == listOfSizes.get(2)) {
            longestList = firstList;
        }
        else if (secondList.size() == listOfSizes.get(2)) {
            longestList = secondList;
        } else {
            longestList = thirdList;
        }

        /**
         * Searching for the longer
         */
        if (firstList.size() == listOfSizes.get(1)) {
            longerList = firstList;
        }
        else if (secondList.size() == listOfSizes.get(1)) {
            longerList = secondList;
        } else {
            longerList = thirdList;
        }

        /**
         * Searching for the long
         */
        if (firstList.size() == listOfSizes.get(0)) {
            longList = firstList;
        }
        else if (secondList.size() == listOfSizes.get(0)) {
            longList = secondList;
        } else {
            longList = thirdList;
        }

        String result = "long: " + longList.toString() + ", longer: " + 
longerList.toString() + ", longest: " + longestList.toString();
        return result;
    }

}
```

What I have above is in a bid to find the intersection of the three. But for error handling I have decided to sort from the largest down to avoid empty lists.

Comment: "Optimised" in what way? Performance? Amount of code? Code complexity? Storage used? Something else?

Comment: A naive way to do that would be a `List<List<String>>` which you sort by using a `Comparator<List<String>>` to compare list sizes.

Comment: @Andreas , Amount of code. The If(s) seems too much.

Comment: Define "long" and "longer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To optimized for minimum amount of code, use streams:

```
public static String sortLists(List<String> firstList, List<String> secondList, List<String> thirdList) {
    List<List<String>> sorted = Stream.of(firstList, secondList, thirdList)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return "long: " + sorted.get(0) + ", longer: " + sorted.get(1) + ", longest: " + sorted.get(2);
}
```

For a pre-Java 8 solution, you can do it like this:

```
public static String sortLists(List<String> firstList, List<String> secondList, List<String> thirdList) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String>[] lists = new List[] { firstList, secondList, thirdList };
    Arrays.sort(lists, new Comparator<List<?>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<?> list1, List<?> list2) {
            return list1.size() - list2.size();
        }
    });
    return "long: " + lists[0] + ", longer: " + lists[1] + ", longest: " + lists[2];
}
```

Comment: Is there a point in using wildcards in your second example when you still use the specific generic types the parameters? I would either define every generic as String or only use wildcard (when you can also remove the SuppressWarnings annotation), but not mix that.

Comment: @Tom I used wildcards in `Comparator` to type less code and make it more generic. I didn't use wildcards in `sortLists` method, to retain the method signature given in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Stream API approach to reducing the amount of code:

```
static String sortLists(List<String> firstList, List<String> secondList, List<String> thirdList) {
     return Stream.of(firstList, secondList, thirdList)
                  .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size))
                  .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), f -> "long: " + f.get(0) + ", longer: " +
                         f.get(1) + ", longest: " + f.get(2)));
}
```

create a stream from the three lists, then sort by their sizes and then finally apply a finishing function to get the expected format.

imports required:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java 8, i would recommend an approach using the Stream API.

If you want an approach with arbitary types:

```
public static List<List<?>> sortBySize(List<?>... lists) {
    return Arrays.stream(lists).sorted(Comparator.comparing(List::size))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Using a generic type parameter if the lists are of the same type:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> List<List<T>> sortBySize(List<T>... lists) {
    return Arrays.stream(lists).sorted(Comparator.comparing(List::size))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```